# How to access sqlite using threads in android

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, exception

I have random number generator.I need to enter that random numbers in to sqlite database using thread .I wrote this code but after few times it will close the app .I'm new to android i'm confused about this I have to complete this with in next 2 days please help me to do this this is my first sqlite experience (I remove some code parts because exceed to character limit and also sorry for post whole code because i'm identify which is wrong part)

My database class

```
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

    protected Dbhelper ourhelper;
    protected final Context ourcontext;
    protected SQLiteDatabase ourdatabase;

    protected static class Dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public Dbhelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + STATUS_TABLE + ");

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + AVE_STATUS_TABLE + );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+STATUS_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+AVE_STATUS_TABLE);


            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public DatabaseClass(Context c) {
        ourcontext = c;

    }
```

I wrote queries in separate class

```
public class DB_queryClass extends DatabaseClass {

    private static final int MAX_ROW_STA = 4;
    private static final int MAX_ROW_AVESTA = 4;
    private static final int AVE_PER = 3;
    private static final int MAX_ROW_DEFECT = 10;

    // private static final double AVE_NUM = 4.0;

    public DB_queryClass(Context c) {
        super(c);


    }

    public DatabaseClass open() throws SQLException {

        ourhelper = new Dbhelper(ourcontext);
        ourdatabase = ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();

        return this;

    }

    // Database close method
    public void close() {

        ourhelper.close();

    }

// Data Entry method to STATUS table
    public long enterStatusData(int vID, String date, String time, String fuel,
            String mafr, String odo, String speed, String torque, String eload,
            String gpsX, String gpsY, String PID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (rowCount(STATUS_TABLE) > MAX_ROW_STA) {

            deleteFirstEntry_Status();
        }
        if (rowCount(STATUS_TABLE) > 0) {
            if (getdata_sta_last() % AVE_PER == 0) {

                enterAveStatusData();
            }
        }

        if (!PID.equals("0")) {
            enterDefect(date, time, PID);
        }
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


        return ourdatabase.insert(STATUS_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
// Data Entry method to Average STATUS table
    public long enterAveStatusData() {

        if (rowCount(AVE_STATUS_TABLE) > MAX_ROW_AVESTA) {
            deleteFirstEntry_AveStatus();
        }

        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_VID, KEY_DATE, KEY_TIME,
                KEY_MAFR, KEY_FUEL, KEY_ELOAD, KEY_SPEED, KEY_TORQUE, KEY_GPSX,
                KEY_GPSY, KEY_ODO, KEY_PID };

        Cursor c = ourdatabase.query(STATUS_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);

        c.moveToLast();

        int iVid = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VID);

        int iTime = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME);
        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
        int iFuel = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FUEL);
        int iCo2 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MAFR);
        int iOdo = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ODO);
        int iSpeed = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SPEED);
        int iTorque = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TORQUE);
        int ieload = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ELOAD);
        int ipid = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PID);

        String Vid = c.getString(iVid);
        double Sspeed = 0;
        int sco2 = 0;
        int storque = 0;
        int seload = 0;
        String Sdate = c.getString(iDate);
        String Stime = c.getString(iTime);
        String Fuel = c.getString(iFuel);
        String Spid = c.getString(ipid);
        String Sodo = c.getString(iOdo);
        int AVE_NUM = 1;
        if (rowCount(STATUS_TABLE) > 0)
            AVE_NUM = rowCount(STATUS_TABLE);

        for (c.moveToLast(); !c.isBeforeFirst(); c.moveToPrevious()) {
            Sspeed = Sspeed + c.getDouble(iSpeed);
            sco2 = sco2 + c.getInt(iCo2);
            storque = storque + c.getInt(iTorque);
            seload = seload + c.getInt(ieload);
        }
        c.close();

        return ourdatabase.insert(AVE_STATUS_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
```

I tried to enter values using this thread

```
public class Datainput implements Runnable {

    int Vid;
    Context C;

    public Datainput(Context c, int vid) {
        C = c;
        Vid = vid;

    }



    public void datainsert(int vid) {



        while (x < 5000) {

        //random number generate part

                final int vid_enter = vid;
                final String date = dateGet.format(new Date());
                final String time = timeGet.format(new Date());
                final String fuel_enter = Double.toString(rem_fuel);
                final String mafr_enter = Double.toString(17);//MAFR
                final String odo_enter = Double.toString(odometre);
                final String speed_enter = Integer.toString(z);
                final String torque_enter = Integer.toString(randomData.nextInt(50));
                final String gpsX_enter = Integer.toString(0);
                final String gpsY_enter = Integer.toString(0);
                String Pid_enter = "0";

                if(x%50==0){
                    eload=randomData.nextInt(50);

                }
                final String eload_enter = Integer.toString(eload);

                String[] array2 = { "p1234", "p3456", "p6789" };


                int number = randomData.nextInt(20);

                if (number == 12) {
                    int number2 = randomData.nextInt(array2.length - 1);
                    Pid_enter = array2[number2];

                } else {

                    Pid_enter = "0";
                }

                try {
                    DB_queryClass dbq = new DB_queryClass(C);
                    dbq.open();
                    final long b = dbq.enterStatusData(vid_enter, date, time,
                            fuel_enter, mafr_enter, odo_enter, speed_enter,
                            torque_enter, eload_enter, gpsX_enter, gpsY_enter,
                            Pid_enter);

                    dbq.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
            x++;
            y0 = y;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        datainsert(Vid);

    }

}
```

I got these errors in log cat

```
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2105)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2197)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2193)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2158)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1130)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:1920)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/System(822):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.Helloworld.adas_saga/databases/ADAS_DB' 
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1949)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1011)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:990)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1055)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:800)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at com.Helloworld.adas_saga.DB_queryClass.open(DB_queryClass.java:26)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at com.Helloworld.adas_saga.Display$1$1.run(Display.java:139)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
11-03 10:09:47.783: E/SQLiteDatabase(822):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a reentrantlock in your database helper and lock and unlock everywhere you access your database. This should allow threads to wait for database availability and avoid a crash/error. e.g. In Database Helper:

```
public static Lock l = new ReentrantLock(false);
```

Everywhere you access the database:

```
l.lock();
try
{
       //do database editing
}
finally
{
      l.unlock();
}
```

However as previously mentioned, if you try to write to the database more times per second than your database edit can actually complete you will end up with a long backlog of database writes. My suggestion would be to use a timestamp comparrison everytime the trigger for your database writing occurs and skip writing to the database unless it has been, for example, half a second since you last wrote that information to the database.